# Use NGINX to proxy webmin in /admin

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, webmin

I am setting up an NGINX to be a WAF (Web Application Firewall).

NGINX reverse proxy is working fine for https://hostname/, but I would like to make https://hostname/admin to be proxied into a Webmin interface.

The scenario is as follows:
Internet NET = 0.0.0.0/32
Network LAN = 6.0.0.0/8
Network DMZ = 11.0.0.0/8

As NET=(router)=LAN=(nginx)=DMZ=(a few virtual machines)
    |--->dmz>---|

So far all is working fine, but now I want to create a Webmin into each virtual machine to be accessed by adding /admin at the end of the hostname

such as https://nas/admin

An example of the configuration file located in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled is:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    server_name nas;
    location /.well-known {
            alias /var/www/nas/.well-known;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_buffers 16 4k;
        proxy_buffer_size 2k;
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass          https://11.0.0.12:443;
        proxy_read_timeout  90;
    }
    location /admin {
        proxy_pass          https://11.0.0.12:10000;
    }
    client_max_body_size 10G;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/nas/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/nas/privkey.pem;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name nas;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any error/error code? What exactly is not working? Have you made a port forwarding in the firewall for nginx accessing a different network?

Comment: It shows the login page, but not with images and style.

Then, when I log in the URL loses the /admin.

Answer (score 0):

For the problem losing the images/styles:

The Webmin interface probably uses a mix of relative and absolute paths. That's why you don't get the images. You need the sub module: `--with-http_sub_module`

Something like this could help:

```
location /admin {
    sub_filter 'https://11.0.0.12:10000/' '/';
    sub_filter_once off;
    proxy_pass          https://11.0.0.12:10000;
}
```

For the redirect problem this could help:

```
proxy_redirect https://11.0.0.12:10000/  /;
```

or

```
proxy_redirect /  /admin/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
location /admin/ { 
    rewrite ^/admin/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass          https://11.0.0.12:10000; 
}
```

Comment: Welcome on the SU. Please explain, what it does and how.

Answer (score 0):

No extra modules are needed. Some webmin config is needed.

`sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/FQDN.conf`

```
location /admin/ {
      # proxy_buffering       off;
        proxy_pass            http://127.0.0.1:10000/;
        proxy_set_header      Host $host;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect        http://$host:10000/ http://$host/admin/;
}
```

save and close.

`sudo nginx -t`
`sudo systemctl reload nginx`

Update webmin config

`sudo nano /etc/webmin/config`

add to eof

```
relative_redir=0
referers=www.FQDN.com FQDN.com
webprefix=/admin
webprefixnoredir=1
```

save and close.
Update miniserv

`sudo nano /etc/webmin/miniserv.conf`

Change `ssl=1` > `ssl=0`
(this is because nginx should handle the ssl first)

add at eof

```
ssl_redirect=0
```

Run command:

`sudo systemctl restart webmin`

Goto FQDN.com/admin or [www.FQDN.com/admin](http://www.FQDN.com/admin)